# Magento add to cart button not working 500 error display

Tags: magento-1.9

On my website when I click on the product add to cart button then its display "HTTP ERROR 500" display.

[image]

Comment: check your logs.... and also enabled developer mode

Comment: check in incognito browser and refresh cache

Comment: Same issue on incognito browser also

Comment: Someone help on this

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure where to find the web server logs (the error details are there), open index.php file and uncomment the following line

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

So, you will have in result

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Save the file and try the add to cart operation once again. You should get the error details on your screen. Do not forget to comment the mentioned line once you have the error details, especially on the production environment.

Comment: I apply same instruction which you have given but still 500 error been display

Comment: Try checking `/var/log/apache2/error.log` on your server or, if there's no such directory, try `/var/log/httpd/error.log`. The errors log place depends on the server configuration.

Answer (score -2):

1. Clear the all Magento cache
2. Clear all your browser cache.

Check the again it's working fine.